# Alternative to passing a parameter to a getter in Angular component

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have a number of controls in my component consisting av label, input and a validation field like shown below.

```
form: FormGroup;
get c1_invalid(): boolean {
  const control = this.form.get("c1");
  return !control.valid && !control.pristine;
}
get c2_invalid(): boolean {
  const control = this.form.get("c2");
  return !control.valid && !control.pristine;
}
```

I'm going to end up with a lot of code this way and the only deviation between the getters is the name of the control to be fetched from the form. I can't pass the ID as a parameter.

What would be a best practice to handle it?

Comment: Replacing the getters with a method looks like the obvious solution. Why can't you pass `"c1"` or `"c2"` as a parameter?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Because in the HTML it's used like `*ngIf="c1_invalid"` and I can't pass that in a bound property. Or can I? Never seen it done that way so I might have assumed a falsity here...

Comment: If you replace the getters with a method, you can call it in the directive: `*ngIf="isInvalid('c1')"`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Got it. Feel free to repost the comment as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple pipe for it:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'isInvalidControl'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  transform(control: FormControl): boolean {
    return !control.valid && !control.pristine;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
*ngIf="form.get('c1') | isInvalidControl"
```

If you are aware of performance of your app you should avoid methods calls in templates.

Comment: This will not work when we explicitly/Or on Some condition set Validation on control. The pipe will not trigger. @nsajdok